# Publication status, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to change the status of hotels in my site. When user create new hotel, he have status "pending". As an administrator, I can upgrade the hotel status from pending to approved or rejected. But I can not approved of in the rejected and vice versa.
I decided to do it with three buttons in admin panel in the place where showing all hotels but this code not working.

**routes.rb**

```
HotelAdvisor::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admins
  devise_for :users
  devise_scope :admin do
    get '/admin', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
  end
  post '/rate' => 'rater#create', :as => 'rate'
  root to: 'hotels#list'

  resources :hotels do
    resources :comments
    get 'list', on: :collection
    post 'comment'
  end

  resources :ratings, only: :update

  namespace :admin do
    resources :hotels, :users
  end
```

[image: Folder hierarchy]

**base_controller**

```
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_admin!

  layout 'admin'
end
```

**hootels_controller(in admin folder)**

```
class Admin::HotelsController < Admin::BaseController

  def index
    @hotels = Hotel.all
  end

  def new
    @hotel = Hotel.new
  end

  def create
    @hotel = Hotel.new(hotel_params)
    @hotel.user_id = current_admin.id
    if @hotel.save
      render :index
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])
    @hotel.update_attributes(params[:hotel])
  end

end
```

[image: views hierarchy]

**index(in /admin/hotels)**

```
- @hotels.each do |hotel|
  .ui.segment
    .ui.three.column.grid
      .column
        .ui.large.image
          =image_tag hotel.avatar_url
          =link_to hotel_path(hotel), class:'blue ui corner label' do
            %i.fullscreen.icon
      .column
        .ui.message
          .header
            =hotel.title
          .wraper=hotel.description.truncate(300)
      .column
        =simple_form_for Hotel.find([hotel.id]),:method => :put do |f|
          =f.hidden_field :status, value: 'approved'
          =f.button :submit, 'Approved', class: 'secondary button'
  %br
  %hr
```

I don't know why, but I see this error,

> Missing template hotels/update, application/update with...

I think out that in updating rails do not use the controller in the folder admin. Perhaps this is causing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you didn't implement what to be done, e.g. `render`, `redirect`, etc. rails fallbacks to the default, which is to render views with the name of the action, in this case, `update`.

You might want to take some action, depending on the outcome of `update_attributes`, for instance:

```
if @hotel.update_attributes(params[:hotel])
  redirect_to(@hotel)
else
  render(:edit)
end
```

You might also want to take a look at [Responders](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.1/classes/ActionController/Responder.html) to DRY your actions.